# RadioButton vs Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-radiobutton

This is more of an opinion based question.

I'm working on an app that will give the user a choice of 2 items of which the user must choose one. Now to implement this, we have :-

1. `RadioButton`s in a `RadioGroup`
2. `Spinner`

For such a basic thing, I think I can should go with `RadioButton` but they don't look much aesthetically pleasing as much a `Spinner` looks but a `Spinner` is basically used for more than 2 items generally.

So I'm all confused as what would be better UI/UX wise.

Can someone please help me out on this one?

Comment: What are the two options? Is it an on/off thing or is it like a male/female thing?

Comment: To select a file from storage or to type the text in the `EditText`

Comment: I think it really depends on the space you have available: less space = spinner.

Comment: I have the whole screen width available with me

Comment: @tambykojak - It is know as Tabs in Android. And it is only used for Top-level views and it's not useful in my case

Answer (score 0):

For two options, why not use a Toggle Button?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html